# rails 3.2: after_update is also called when destroying elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

We have small class, that has a related class

```
class Car
  has_one :engine, :dependent => :destroy

  after_update :save_engine


  delegate :oil_level, :oil_level=, :to => :engine

  def save_engine
    engine.save if engine
  end
end
```

As you can tell, we are trying to work-around the problem that childs are not automatically saved in rails. So we can set the `oil_level` on car, and it will store it in `engine` correctly when saving.

Now what happens when we try to delete the car? Apparently the `engine` is never deleted, and this is caused by the `after_update` which will re-save the just deleted engine. So the car is succesfully deleted, but the engine is recreated (a new id), and no longer linked to a car. I want the engine to be deleted correctly.

I did find a solid work-around:

```
class Car
  has_one :engine, :dependent => :destroy

  after_update :save_engine
  before_destroy :set_destroying


  delegate :oil_level, :oil_level=, :to => :engine

  def set_destroying
    @destroying = true
  end

  def save_engine
    engine.save if engine && !@destroying
  end
end
```

But it still feels a bit dirty, like there should be a better way to do this.
It seems a bit unlogical that `after_update` is called when destroying. 
Is there a specific rails-way to know what action is actually in progress in a callback (saving/creating/destroying) ?.

In short: what is the proper way to handle this? Or is this actually some kind of rails-bug? Or is this intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't done Rails for a while, so I may be off topic, but have you considered using the `:autosave` option?

Comment: This sounds like it could be exactly what I need. I will try this, and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure that in car_controller def destroy calls car.destroy NOT car.delete, or the callback will be missed and engine won't be destroyed.

2) is the engine not being deleted (same id) or being recreated? (diff id), you seem to jump from one to the other in your description.

Comment: Yes I call `car.destroy`, and the engine is recreated with a different id. I clarified my question a bit. My workaround does work, so I have a working solution, but I suspect there should be a better way.

Comment: Hum, I think I've failed on this one as I'm not up to scratch on 3.2, but I would have expected delegate to function like car.engine.build() which would mean that the save is called on engine as the car is saved. I could write this up clean in another way of you like, but otherwise I'd just switch the order of your hooks:   before_update :save_engine
  after_destroy :set_destroying

Comment: Mmmm you don't seem to completely understand my question. My hooks are fine, and work. The question is: the `after_update` is also called when destroying my car, which will save my engine (again), which is supposed to be deleted by the `:dependent => :destroy`. So in the `before_destroy` I set the switch so I will not save the engine when destroying. That works. So the order of the hooks is correct. However: do you know a cleaner way? Why is the `after_update` also called when destroying? Instead of setting the `@destroying` is there a cleaner way to know we are destroying inside a callback?